# How to move a marker on google maps api with PHP?

Tags: php, maps

http://code.google.com/intl/tr-TR/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlajax.html#createmap
im using the tutorial linked above
in tutorial they explain how to add markers with php &mysql

but i need to get latitude and longtitude by moving markers??
im a javascript beginner. how can i do it easily?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need are the [`.getPosition()`](http://code.google.com/intl/tr-TR/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Marker) method of the marker and the [`.addListener`](http://code.google.com/intl/tr-TR/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MapsEventListener) method of `google.maps.event`.  So all you need to do is listen for the `dragend` event of the marker and then pull out the `LatLong` location of the event.  That will give you the new `LatLong` of the marker, which you can then send back to your PHP script if desired.

Comment: im trying to find out how that getPosition() function works i added it into dragend event but it is returning me any latlong value.

Comment: var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
      var point = new GLatLng(51.49, -0.12);
      var marker = new GMarker(point, { draggable: true });
      map.setCenter(point, 8);
      map.addOverlay(marker);
      function toggleDrag() {
        if (marker.draggingEnabled()) {
          marker.disableDragging();
        }
        else {
          marker.enableDragging();
        }
      }
   GEvent.addListener(marker, 'dragend',
function(event) {
 GMarkerManager.refresh();
      document.form.box.value=marker.getPosition();
    }); 
this is the script i use
it stucksafter drag

Comment: ok i just found an example on my issue
http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-samples-v3/source/browse/trunk/draggable-markers/draggable-markers.html?spec=svn49&r=49